# Streamlit session state pulling everything at once causing Duplicate Widget Error

Tags: python, pandas, session-state, streamlit

I keep getting the error:
"DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple widgets with the same key='submit_answer'."

I am trying to loop through the questions however it looks like it's still pulling all sessions states at the same time. Which then throws the duplicate widget error.

So I was curious what should be changed with the session state code so that it would iterate through better? Or open for any other recommendations. I am trying to create a game of yes/no questions. Where you could answer one question at at time and it tell you if you were right or wrong. And then also give a total score at the end.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def main():
    st.title('Employer Test') # Check if 'started' key exists in session_state, if not, display candidate information  
    
    if not st.session_state.get('started'):
        st.markdown('## Candidate Information') 
    
    # Full Name Input 
    full_name = st.text_input('Full Name') 
    
    # Experience Dropdown 
    experience = st.selectbox("Experience", [" Showcase"], index=0) 
    
    # Language Dropdown 
    language = st.selectbox("Type of Game", [" Game"], index=0) 
   
    # Button to start the test  
    
    if st.button('Submit'): 
        if full_name:
            st.session_state['started'] = True
            st.session_state['full_name'] = full_name
            run_python_test() 
    else: 
        run_python_test()


def run_python_test():
    
    st.title('Is the follow statement or question related to XYZ') 
    # Dummy test questions and answers 
    questions = [
        { 'question': 'Question 1',
          'options': ['Yes', 'No'], 
          'correct_answer': 'Yes' 
        },
        { 
          'question': 'Question 2', 
          'options': ['Yes', 'No'], 
          'correct_answer': 'No' 
        },
        { 
          'question': 'Question 3', 
          'options': ['Yes', 'No'], 
          'correct_answer': 'Yes' 
        } 
        # Add more questions here... 
    ]

    total_questions = len(questions) 
    if  'answer' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['answer'] = [''] * total_questions 
    for i, question_data in enumerate(questions):
        question = question_data['question']
        
        st.write(f'Question {i+1}: {question}') 
        
        # Display options for each question 
        st.session_state['answer'][i] = st.text_area(f"Enter answer for Question {i+1}", value=st.session_state['answer'][i], key=f"answer_{i}") 

        
        # Add a submit button  
        if st.button("Submit Test", key="submit_answer"):
            score = 0 
            # Process the answers and calculate score  
            for i, ans in enumerate(st.session_state['answer']): 
                if ans == questions[i]['correct_answer']:
                    score += 1
                st.write(f"Question {i+1} Answer: {ans}")
        
            percentage_score = (score / total_questions) * 100 
        
            if percentage_score >= 60:
                save_result(st.session_state['full_name'], percentage_score)
                st.session_state['test_completed'] = True

def save_result(full_name, score):
    data = {'Full Name':[full_name], 'Score':[score]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('test_results.csv',index=False)
    st.write('Result saved')
    
                               
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streamlit `st.session_state` behaves like a dictionary, so that you can have only unique identifiers as keys. Moreover, [each widget created with an explicit key is added to the state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state#session-state-and-widget-state-association).

That said, your issue is that you are creating a submit button with the same key for each question. If you want to create a button for each question, you need to give unique identifiers to them, just like:

```
for i, question_data in enumerate(questions):
    # ...
    if st.button("Submit Test", key=f"submit_answer_{i}"):
       # ...
```

Otherwise, you can reconfigure you app to maybe use [st.form](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form) and [st.form_submit_button](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form_submit_button).

Comment: Thank you that worked, really appreciate it.